# Angular UI-Grid 3 - how to programatically sort?

Tags: angularjs, sorting

The question says it all. I can set the column, on which to sort, in code:

```
cols[colIdx].sort = { direction: uiGridConstants.DESC, priority: 1 };
```

But it doesn't actually perform the sort, just puts a sort icon in the header. User has to actually click on the column header for the sort to occur. What additional code do I need to have the sort happen programmatically?

Been at this for hours, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.
Rick.

Answer (score 2):

From the `gridApi` you can call `gridApi.grid.sortColumn(column)`.

Comment: This is the correct approach. Also, answer here will help get you in the right direction - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650456/how-to-update-sort-indicators-in-ui-grid-programmatically